# Push element in a nested array ( Mongodb )

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

My Mongodb database collection named `msgs` looks like this :

```
[
   { 
     "_id" : ObjectId("5b45c387d774550874df7d47"),
     "userID" : "olivia",
     "friends" : [ 
                   { "userID" : "tom", "messages" : [ ] },
                   { "userID" : "sophia", "messages" : [ ] },
                   { "userID" : "katrina", "messages" : [ ] }  
                 ] 
   }
   { 
     "_id" : ObjectId("5b45c39fd774550874df7d4a"),
     "userID" : "tom",
     "friends" : [ 
                   { "userID" : "steve", "messages" : [ ] },
                   { "userID" : "olivia", "messages" : [ ] } 
                 ] 
   }
]
```

I want to update this collection by pushing a message in the `"messages"` array.

In the front end, maybe the user `olivia` sends a message (in string format) to the user `tom`. So I want to write a statement that pushes the message (any string) in olivia users' message array.

For eg :

If `olivia` sends a message `"Hey Tom!"` to `tom`. I want the new database as follows :

```
[
   { 
     "_id" : ObjectId("5b45c387d774550874df7d47"),
     "userID" : "olivia",
     "friends" : [ 
                   { "userID" : "tom", "messages" : [ { "text" : "Hey Tom!" } ] },
                   { "userID" : "sophia", "messages" : [ ] },
                   { "userID" : "katrina", "messages" : [ ] }  
                 ] 
   }
   { 
     "_id" : ObjectId("5b45c39fd774550874df7d4a"),
     "userID" : "tom",
     "friends" : [ 
                   { "userID" : "steve", "messages" : [ ] },
                   { "userID" : "olivia", "messages" : [ ] } 
                 ] 
   }
]
```

I tried this statement but it didn't work:

```
db.msgs.update({"userID":"olivia","friends.userID":"tom"},{$push:{"messages":{text:"Hey Tom!"}}})
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the $elemMatch tag and "$" positional operator to access the fields inside the array.

Here is your query.

```
db.msgs.update({"userID":"olivia","friends":{$elemMatch:{"userID":"tom"}}},{$push:{"friends.$.messages":{text:"hello"}}})
```